# Bash: How to check if a number of operations finished successfully?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script which does all kinds of operations, example from the script:

```
scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv13:$workdir
  scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv179:$workdir
  ssh root@$srv13 "hostname ; service httpd restart"
  ssh root@localhost "hostname ; service httpd restart"
  ssh root@$srv179 "hostname ; service httpd restart"
  ssh root@$srv201 "hostname ; service named restart"
```

I want to return some "operation successful" indication but I want to be sure that all operations finished successfully.
Usually I'd use `if [ $? = 0 ]; then...` but I wanted to know if there's any other way to do that as writing 5x`if's` doesn't seem like going with the way of "least administrative effort".
So, is there another way to bulk check the exit codes of these 5 operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to fail if any of the operations fails, then simply do `set -e` at the top of the scripts. Then it will fail as soon as any step fails.

If you are ok with any individual step failures, but only want to keep track of the number of failures then you can try this:

```
success_count=0
scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv13:$workdir && success_count=$((success_count+1))
scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv179:$workdir && success_count=$((success_count+1))
ssh root@$srv13 "hostname ; service httpd restart" && success_count=$((success_count+1))
ssh root@localhost "hostname ; service httpd restart" && success_count=$((success_count+1))
ssh root@$srv179 "hostname ; service httpd restart" && success_count=$((success_count+1))
ssh root@$srv201 "hostname ; service named restart" && success_count=$((success_count+1))

echo "Num ops succeeded = $success_count"
```

You can even pull it into a function, like:

```
exec_with_count() {
    "$@" && success_count=$((success_count+1))
}

exec_with_count scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv13:$workdir
exec_with_count scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv179:$workdir
...

echo "Num ops succeeded = $success_count"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can chain the operations with `&&` but maybe you ruled that out already too?

```
scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv13:$workdir &&
  scp $workdir/$site$dom.conf root@$srv179:$workdir &&
  ssh root@$srv13 "hostname service httpd restart" &&
  ssh root@localhost "hostname  service httpd restart" &&
  ssh root@$srv179 "hostname service httpd restart" &&
  ssh root@$srv201 "hostname service named restart" &&
  echo "All ok"
```

Comment: Since you chained all the commands, might as well chain the last `echo`.